# BABYLONJS : I need to create the 2D background stag of 720*480 and with responsive as per aspect ration of screen

Tags: html, game-engine, game-physics, babylonjs, babel-babylon

Folks,
I am currently using phaser js but now i am try to implement babylonjs,

I need to create stage 720*480 static stage that will not transferred into 3D.

Stage should be STILL.

An it is responsive based on the aspect ratio of the browser or the screen.

I tried various option but i didnt get any success.

Thank in ADVANCED

Answer (score 0):

Try a BABYLON.Layer :)

```
new BABYLON.Layer(name: string, imgUrl: Nullable<string>);
```

https://doc.babylonjs.com/api/classes/babylon.layer

http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#UUXLX#15